# Cannot get the thumbnail for some videos using the Videos API

Tags: linkedin-api

When I'm trying to get the thumbnail for a video using the Videos API, I receive a 500 Internal server error (this video was posted last week on LinkedIn).

I had tried with others videos with mp4 and movs extensions and some of them works and others don’t, on both company and profile. The video from the screenshots is a mp4 and the media id is urn:li:video:D4D05AQEuZHjf3NPyDA (encoded is urn%3Ali%3Avideo%3AD4D05AQEuZHjf3NPyDA)

Request: `GET https://api.linkedin.com/rest/videos/urn%3Ali%3Avideo%3AD4D05AQEuZHjf3NPyDA`
Response:

```
{
    "message": "Internal Server Error",
    "status": 500
}
```

[[get the video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jqV9.png)]
[[get thumbnail for the video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWasy.png)]

Comment: I have the same issue, so frustrating